# what is a reified String, instead of a null

Tags: swift, kotlin

I was reading this [blog](http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2017/01/11/TheDarkPath.html) and cannot understand what is meant below for reified String.

> Both Swift and Kotlin have incorporated the concept of nullable
>   types. The fact that a variable can contain a null becomes part of the
>   type of that variable. **A variable of type String cannot contain a
>   null; it can only contain a reified String**. On the other hand, a
>   variable of type String? has a nullable type and can contain a null.
>
> The rules of the language insist that when you use a nullable
>   variable, you must first check that variable for null. So if s is a
>   String? then var l = s.length() won’t compile. Instead you have to say
>   var l = s.length() ?: 0 or var l = if (s!=null) s.length() else 0.

Comment: doh!, I thought was something related to generics reified, thanks

Comment: @StatelessDev A concrete String value, not a *literal*. That's really something completely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reified means "make (something abstract) more concrete or real".Here reified string means if string is null, then that string output contains as 0 or any other value.

Comment: Thank for your contribution, if you compare it to reified generics at compile time, and extend the concept of reified to nullability I am gonna accept your response and upvote you eventually, because stateless dev already replied in the comment and I gave him back feedback